# How to translate text using aws translate api for more than 10000bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, translation

Aws translation allows only 10000 bytes, how to translate for more than 10000bytes

I tried nltk lib but is there any other way

Comment: You can call it multiple times, passing a maximum of 10,000 bytes each call. You should break-up the text by sentences if possible, rather than splitting a sentence between calls.